# Throttle Mechanize gem

Tags: ruby, mechanize, web-scraping

Is there any built-in way to throttle Mechanize gem?

I'm searching something like a callback on making an HTTP request.

*Later edit*:
I would like to implement [bandwith throttling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth_throttling), to avoid flooding parsed sites.
EG: Only allow one request per second.

Comment: What do you mean? What do you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that [pre_connect_hooks](https://github.com/tenderlove/mechanize/blob/master/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb#L32) is what you are looking for. Sadly, I am unable to find any way to add one but adding directly a lambda/Proc to the array.

They are called [here](https://github.com/tenderlove/mechanize/blob/master/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb#L284) and this method is called [here](https://github.com/tenderlove/mechanize/blob/master/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb#L183)